# Modal Window creation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a modal window so i wrote the following HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$("#btn-show-modal").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#dialog-example").modal('show');
});
});


</head>
<body>

<p> <a href="#" id="btn-show-modal">Show modal dialog </a>  
<div id="dialog-example" class="modal hide"> 
        <div class="modal-header">  
        <h1>My Modal Dialog</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">  
        <p>This is a modal body</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But after running the HTML page on the browser I am not able to get any dialog box. My requirement is to get the dialog box and the dialog box should close after 10 seconds .

Comment: what does the JavaScript Console say?

Comment: You're trying to call function modal() that is not defined. You're probably missing dependency on a jquery plugin that has this function defined.

Comment: self: The output is nothing on the browser

Comment: @Petr : I tried using <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> but still i am not getting any output

Comment: Sudpto: That's the jquery core. You also need either some plugin that defines function modal() or define the function by yourself.

Comment: @PetrHejda he is including bootstrap.min.js, which defines the `.modal()` method. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api

Something else is going on with his code.

Comment: Shouldn't you close your `<script>`-tag if you want it to work?

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: I tried closing the script tag. BUt it still do not work

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- you did not close your `<script>`-Tag
- don't set the `hide`-attribute on your modal `<div id="dialog-example">` or only the backdrop will show.

I have removed the jQuery-code and switched it to the declarative style preferred by Bootstrap, find it here: https://jsbin.com/fusirecowa/edit?html,output - if you want to stick with the imperative style, your code should still work after you close the `<script>`-tag.

```
<body>
    <p> <a href="#" id="btn-show-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog-example">Show modal dialog </a>  
    <div id="dialog-example" class="modal"> 
            <div class="modal-header">  
            <h1>My Modal Dialog</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">  
            <p>This is a modal body</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help . I was able to implement by using the following

```
//alert("entering");
  $("#dialog").dialog({
         modal: true,
         //title: "Confirm",
         resizable: false,
         width: 300,
         height: 150,
         open: function (event, ui) 
         {
               setTimeout(function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close");}, 5000);
               alert("entering again");
               //sleep(5000);
         },
         buttons: {
             Ok: function () {
                // $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Ok
             },
             Cancel: function () {
                // $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Cancel
             }
         }

     });
```